# Why can't I draw on my mesh but I can fill?

Tags: texture-painting

Trying to paint my mesh, but for some reason the paintbrush doesn't work, and the fill does. How do I fix that?

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to give us a clue. Please show  screen-grab(s) showing  any  settings that might help.

Comment: @RobinBetts could I just send you the file? it might be easier

Comment: For sure. To share, we use https://blend-exchange.com/ . Follow the instructions there, and paste the link into your question with an edit.

Comment: @RobinBetts here ya go
https://blend-exchange.com/b/eeQvKeQ9

Comment: Have you checked for inverted normals ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an all-black [Texture Mask](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/brush/texture.html#texture-texture-mask) set on your brush, so the paint ain't getting through:

[image]

Hit the '×' to lose it, or replace the texture, if you want a textured brush.

Comment: Okay, I know this got answered already, but I'm having that issue again with the can't paint and this time it's not the black texture. Could you help me with this again?

Comment: Here's a new one
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jy06N5xD" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jy06N5xD/)

Comment: @Zumi  I'm sorry, can't reproduce this problem. It's working OK for me, which suggests tool settings are good. All I had to do was create an image to paint into ..(Naturally, your image isn't packed in the file,) and it worked straight away.